# SQL Aggregate Function in ADO Returns -1 Records

Tags: sql, vba, ado

I'm trying to build a function in VBA using ADO that will run a query in SQL and return the number of records in a table. The query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Queue
```

In SQL Server, this query runs fine and returns a non-null value.  The function I've built runs a SQL query, stores the output and headers to an array, and returns that array so other parts of my code can use it.  I have no problems running it where SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM Queue" , but for some reason when I try using an aggregate function like COUNT(), it breaks.

The reason why it breaks is that RecSet.RecordCount returns -1 and clearly you can't create an array of -1 length, so ReDim Results(dim_x, dim_y) throws a "subscript out of range" error.

I've already tried changing the cursor type and lock type (cursor is currently static) to no avail.  I can copy the record set to Excel using the .copyFromRecordSet method, so I know the data is pulling through correctly, but I need my data in an array and I feel like it's a shoddy workaround to just dump into into Excel and copy it back into a variable.  Any ideas?  The code for the function is below:

```
Function ExecSql(Server as string, DB as string, SQLstr as string)
    Dim Results As Variant
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim dim_x As Integer
    Dim dim_y As Integer

    Dim Conn As Object
    Dim RecSet As Object
    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    Set RecSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

    With Conn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & dbName & ";Trusted_Connection=yes;"
        .Open
    End With
            If Conn.State = 1 Then
                With RecSet
                    .ActiveConnection = Conn
                    .Source = SQLstr
                    .LockType = 3
                    .CursorType = 3
                    .Open
                End With
            Else:
                Conn.Close
                ExecSql = "Connection Failed"
                Exit Function
            End If


            dim_x = RecSet.Fields.count - 1 'counts total fields at index 0, hence subtract 1
            dim_y = RecSet.RecordCount 'add one extra row for headers, i.e. don't subtract 1

            Results = Array()
            temp = Array()
            ReDim Results(dim_x, dim_y)

            'Add headers to array
            For x = 0 To dim_x 'array and recset both start at index 0
                Results(x, 0) = RecSet.Fields(x).Name
            Next x

            'retrieve data
            y = 2
        With RecSet
            If Not .bof And Not .EOF Then
                .movelast
                .movefirst
                temp = .GetRows(dim_y)
            Else
            End If
            .Close
        End With

        'Add data to array
        For y = 1 To dim_y 'start at y = 1, y = 0 is headers
            For x = 0 To dim_x
                Results(x, y) = temp(x, y - 1)
                Debug.Print Results(x, 0) & " - " & temp(x, y - 1)
            Next x
        Next y

        If IsNull(Results) Then
            ExecSql = 0
        Else
            ExecSql = Results
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: Don't bother determining the field/row count independently, if you `temp = .GetRows()` then `temp` will contain all the data - you can then ask `temp` for its row/column count via `ubound()` e.g.  http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_ado_load_array.html

Comment: `RecordCount` is an unreliable way to determine if you got any records or not - it may return -1 even when you have a non-empty recordset. Better to check the recordset's EOF property.

Comment: Thanks guys, I took your suggestions and I have it working now.  One thing though:  when I use an aggregate function, the "If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then .movelast" bit fails because "Rowset does not support fetching backwards", even though the MSDN documentation says you should be able to movelast in this context.  Removing .movelast doesn't seem to be creating any problems, though.  Anything I should watch out for?